# CellType cannot be resolved to a variable setCellType error Apache POI - Java

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache

I was reading the Apache poi guide: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

And I decided to follow along and type the code into my Eclipse project, and while writing the "Reading and Rewriting Workbooks" section, I got this error in eclipse:

> CellType cannot be resolved to a variable

And I was wondering why? I found on another post in Stack Overflow to change this line:

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

to:

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCellType.STRING);//or XSSFCell
```

But it doesn't work, is there anything wrong with my code? (Which btw, I copied and pasted from apache's website)

```
 InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");

 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
 Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
 Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
 if (cell == null)
     cell = row.createCell(3);
 cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
 cell.setCellValue("a test");

 //Write 
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
 wb.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the POI version. `CellType` is only available for new version of POI and the `Cell` is the old version.
My recommendation that you should using POI version 3.15. In this version you would not have to set cell type before set value to it. (It have `setStringValue` or `setDateValue`... for you datatype)

Comment: Okay, downloaded the POI 3.15 jar file.. so I change the `cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);` to `cell.setStringvalue();` ? Sorry, Im not sure how to do this..

Comment: You are right. You just need to use `setStringValue` to set a String to this cell. A [post for your reference](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Change this  `cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);` to  :

```
   cell.setCellType(STRING);
```

Comment: It says ```STRING cannot be resolved to a variable```

Answer (score 0):

Use XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING or CellType.STRING